# Алгоритм генерации уникальных чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть число N, необходимо найти все уникальные числа до 0 до N. Например из чисел 123,132,213,231,312,321 уникальным будет только любое одно, но если N = 321, то скорее всего уникальным будет 123 т.к. в переборе встретиться первым. Простой перебор не подходит, т.к. для long значений он становится очень долгим.

```
boolean isNext = false;
   long num; //Входящее число
   long digit;
   long digit2;
   while (num > 0) {
        digit = num % 10;
        digit2 = num / 10;
        if (digit >= digit2 % 10) {
            isNext = true;
        } else {
            isNext = false;
            break;
        }
        num /= 10;
   }
```

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Comment: Что означает "найти"? Любое число меньше N будет уникальным.

Comment: Пока, вообще нечего не получается. Даже идей нет как это сделать.

Comment: Видимо я не точно описал задачу. Под уникальным я имею ввиду значение состоящее из чисел которые больше не встретятся в следующем значении такой же длины.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 ... 9 10 11 12 ... 19 20 22 23 24 ... 29 30 33 34 35 ... 39 40 44 45 ... 49 .... 90 99 100 101 102 ... 109 111 112 - ну, в общем, намек ясен? если игнорировать нули - просто числа, в которых цифры находятся в неубывающем порядке.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за намек, вроде решил. Правда все равно не укладываюсь по времени в условие задачи

Comment: @Cactus А как звучит точное условие задачи - найти и вывести все числа или посчитать их?

Comment: @MBo это часть решения задачи на поиск всех чисел Армстронга, на которую уходит больше всего времени вычислений.

Comment: @Cactus Это не отвечает на мой вопрос, т.к. мы не знаем, как данная задача включена в общую схему решения. Сомнительно, что какое бы то ни было переборное решение переберёт все числа до 115 132 219 018 763 992 565 095 597 973 971 522 401

Comment: @MBo Число S состоит из M цифр, например, S=370 и M (количество цифр) = 3 Реализовать логику метода getNumbers, который должен среди натуральных чисел меньше N (long) находить все числа, удовлетворяющие следующему критерию: число S равно сумме его цифр, возведенных в M степень getNumbers должен возвращать все такие числа в порядке возрастания.

Это основное условие. А вот тот вопрос который я задал, я сам сформулировал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частичное решение вашей задачи.

Позволяет найти все числа с уникальными комбинациями цифр для указанного количества знаков (n). Не хватает остановки при достижении указанного числа N - ищет все возможные n-значные числа.

Например: найти все уникальные 4-х значные числа - алгоритм найдет все числа от 1 до 9999. Найти все 3-х значные - найдёт числа от 1 до 999.

**Определение уникального числа:**

Уникальным считается то число, которое имеет комбинацию цифр отличную от всех чисел проверенных ранее.

**Пример 1.** Все уникальные двухзначные числа (10 - 99):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Число `21` не является уникальным, так как имеет ту же комбинации цифр, что и число `12`, проверенное ранее.

Число `14` является уникальным, так как это первый из двух возможных вариантов комбинации цифр `1` и `4`. Вторым вариантом является число `41`, но оно ещё не встречалось (соответственно, когда мы до него дойдём оно уже не будет уникальным).

**Пример 2.** Уникальные трёхзначные числа от 100 до 199:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение:**

Предлагаю не проверять все числа на уникальность перебором, а изначально конструировать только уникальные комбинации цифр. Для простоты возьмём числа без нулей (нули требуют дополнительной обработки):

1) Первая цифра любого числа может иметь только девять вариантов: `1`, `2`, `3` ... `9`. Мы будем собирать комбинации для каждой стартовой цифры отдельно - в виде строки. Конечно, нет нужды делать это одновременно, подойдёт цикл прокручивающий числа от `1` до `9` и выполняющий все требуемые действия для каждой строки по очереди.

Итак, возьмём девять начал состоящих из 1 цифры:

```
# В квадратных скобках зафиксированная (неизменяемая) часть
# состоящая из одной цифры.
[1] -> в эту сторону будет расти число
[2] -> в эту сторону будет расти число
[3] -> в эту сторону будет расти число
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
```

Можно представлять вместо чисел кубики - вначале у нас 9 рядов по одному кубику, на следующем шаге мы добавляем справа ещё по одному кубику, потом ещё и т. д. до требуемого количества кубиков (знаков) в ряде.

2) Если текущая цифра равна `1`, то следующая цифра тоже должна быть  `1` или больше и так для каждой последующей цифры. Меньше она быть не может, так как в этом случае мы получим уже пройденную комбинацию. То есть `23` - новая уникальная комбинация, а `21` уже была найдена ранее в числе `12`.

```
[1] <- 1 #присоединяем 1 к уже имеющейся строке.
[2] <- 2 #присоединяем 2 к уже имеющейся строке.
[3] <- 3
[4] <- 4
[5]5
[6]6
[7]7
[8]8
[9]9
```

Обратите внимание, что первая цифра у нас зафиксирована, а вторую мы будем менять, создавая таким образом все возможны двухзначные комбинации.

3) Присоединяем к фиксированная части следующую цифру (предыдущая цифра + 1), до тех пор, пока она не будет равна `9`. Видно, что для числа `99` уже не будет новых комбинаций. А для числа `11` их ещё 8 - `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `18`, `19`. Дойдя в каждом ряде до цифры `9` мы получим все возможные комбинации для конкретной стартовой цифры. А соединив все результаты воедино - все возможные комбинации для данного количества знаков, - что и требовалось.

```
[1] <- 2 #увеличиваем текущую цифру на 1 и добаляем к уже имеющейся строке.
[2] <- 3 #увеличиваем текущую цифру на 1 и добаляем к уже имеющейся строке.
[3] <- 4 #увеличиваем текущую цифру на 1 и добаляем к уже имеющейся строке.
[4] <- 5 #увеличиваем текущую цифру на 1 и добаляем к уже имеющейся строке.
[5]6
[6]7
[7]8
[8]9
[9]9 #данная комбинация, начинающаяся с 9 достигла своего предела.
```

4) Если нужно собрать трёхзначные комбинации, то берём всё возможные двухзначные комбинации полученные на предыдущем этапе, фиксируем их в виде строки и повторяем все шаги, начиная с **пункт 1**. Делать это удобно с помощью рекурсии.

```
# В квадратных скобках зафиксированная часть
# состоящая из двух цифр.
[11] <- 1 #присоединяем 1 к уже имеющейся строке.
[22] <- 2 #присоединяем 2 к уже имеющейся строке.
[33]3     
[44]4
[55]5
[66]6
[77]7
[88]8
[99]9
```

**Реализация на Python:**

```
# head - здесь фиксируется стартовая часть каждой комбинации
###
# start - точка отсчёта для новых комбинаций
###
# digit_num - количество знаков для которого требуется найти комбинации.
# 4 == 3 знака, 3 == 2 знака и т.д.
###
# depth - отслеживаем глубину рекурсии, чтобы остановить её в нужный момент.
# Также используется для понимания порядкового номера знака над которым работаем
# в данный момент. 
def print_uniq_nums(head, start, digit_num, depth):
    if depth >= digit_num:
        return

    if depth > 0:
        print(head)

    # запускаем счётчик от 0 до 9
    # если нули можно было бы не учитывать, как в моём упрощённом
    # объяснении, то можно было начинать отсчёт со  "start",
    # а так как они нужны, то начинаем от нуля, потом пропускаем ненужное
    # и продолжаем со "start"
    for i in range(0, 10):      
        # Чтобы не создавало комбинации типа 001, 002 и т.д.
        if i == 0 and depth == 0:
            continue

        # Для защиты от неправильных комбинаций типа:
        # 110 (уже была: 101), 220 (уже была: 202)
        if i == 0 and depth > 1 and head[depth - 1] != "0":
            continue        

        if i == 0 or i >= start:                
            # прибавляем к фиксированной части, находящейся в head,
            # изменямое окончание и отдаём получившуюся комбинацию
            # на следующий уровень рекурсии
            num_str = "%s%s" % (head, i)

            # Если i == 0, то пробрасываем текущую точку отсчёта
            # на следующий уровень рекурсии, чтобы после
            # нулей счётчик не сбивался. 
            # Иначе будет неправильная комбинация 2001, вместо 2002
            if i > 0:
                start = i

            print_uniq_nums(num_str, start, digit_num, depth + 1)

print_uniq_nums("", 1, 4, 0)
```

**Output (сокращённый):**

```
1
10
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
11
111
112
..............
119
12
122
..............
128
129
13
133
..............
2
20
200
202
..............
207
208
209
22
222
223
..............
```

**Другой вариант решения:**

Перебираем все числа от 0 до N, каждое разбиваем на отдельные цифры и укладываем в массив. Массив сортируем, формируем из него строку, делаем её хэш и добавляем его в хэш-таблицу. В качестве ключа используем получившийся хэш, в качестве значения - `1`. При нахождении следующего числа с такой же комбинацией цифр, увидим, что в хэш-таблице уже есть такой элемент, значит, это число пропускаем.

Answer (score -2):

Представляю свой алгоритм:

```
int [] array={2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1};
list<int> list;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
 {      
int count=0;
   for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
    {   
        if(array[i]==array[j]) count++;
    } 
   if(count==0) list.Add(arra[i]);  // добавляем в список или в любой контейнер
 }
```

Comment: Во-первых, на мой взгляд чтобы ваш код работал корректно нужно добавить проверку во втором цикле на j!=i `if(array[i]==array[j]&&j!=i){count++;}`и я не понял, что находится в array? Все числа от до N или каждое число которое мы проверяем?

Comment: массив в котором хотите найти все уникальные числа, да надо добавить проверку if(array[i]==array[j]&&j!=i){count++;}

Comment: Все равно, ваш алгоритм просто выкинет дубликаты из массива. А должен например из двух 12 и 21, или из шести 123,132,213,231,312,321 чисел оставить одно.

Comment: Если они уникальны-выкинет, если не уникальны,то не выкинет. Вы же этого и хотите сделать